# How do I open an MP4 file without a dedicated application

Tags: windows, web, video-streaming, mp4

How do I open an MP4 file when I don't have a dedicated application? Can I do it with computer code? Is there another way with applications already on Windows?

Comment: Just drag the MP4 file into an empty tab on your browser (Chrome or MS Edge. Firefox will not work with MP4). Windows Media Player should be able to play it also.

Comment: I tested this on my operating system, with both Chrome and Firefox and it didn't appear to work. Does the above solution only work on certain OSs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a few different ways to do it, including writing some HTML5. I have prepared a bit of code which does the job:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>MPlayer Online Media Player</title>
    <meta name="description" content="MPlayer Online Media Player">
    <meta name="author" content="Peter David Carter">
  </head>

  <body>
    <video width="640" height="480" controls>
    <source src="pre-baptism.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
  </body>
</html>
```

and uploaded it here: [MPlayer Media Player](http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/mplayer/mediaplayer.html)

as well as a high-res version here: [MPlayer Media Player Hi-Res](http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/mplayer/mediaplayermk2.html)

to demonstrate, though it may depend what codecs your browser/OS has installed whether you are able to play the video.

Failing that, there are pre-written code solutions in place on Google Drive which do a similar thing. I have uploaded the video there for reference as the Google implementation seems to work reliably across a wider range of systems, regardless of MIME type etc.

[Google Video Player](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B23a5KI12BkXakdGV2tFdjZUX1E)